# How to import third party libary in android app in android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to import third library in our android project i import as module and added library from project Structure Module dependency .

My app configuration is below

compileSdk 34

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myproject.android"
    minSdk 26
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary true
    }
}
```

kotlin version version : 1.5.31
while our external library version

```
 compileSdkVersion 30
    namespace 'com.shawnlin.numberpicker'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 30
    }
```

when i try to sync the project i am getting below error

Invalid MavenPublish Configuration. Unable to find variant to publish named release. Try setting the 'androidVariantToPublish' property in the mavenPublish extension object to something that matches the variant that ought to be published.

can any one help me how to fix this issue

Thanks